# OpenTelemetry .NET HttpClient not propagating TraceId

Tags: asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, open-telemetry, distributed-tracing

I am trying to get Tracing using OpenTelemetry to work with `HttpClient` in an integration test for an Asp.NET API.

Tracing works for everything else, we get traces from the API controllers and all other instrumented libraries.

Configuration looks like this:

```
webApplicationBuilder.Services.AddOpenTelemetryTracing(b =>
    b.SetResourceBuilder(resourceBuilder)
        .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
        .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
        .AddProtoActorInstrumentation()
        .AddRedisInstrumentation()
        .AddOtlpExporter(options =>
        {
            ConfigureOpenTelemetry(webApplicationBuilder, options);
        })
);
```

But when calling the API using HttpClient. the current TraceId is not propagated.
The integration test uses a `MyAppFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Program>` for the test.
And the HttpClient is constructed in the tests using the `factory.CreateClient()` of the MyAppFactory.

If I check the `Activity.Current.TraceId` inside my integration test. I get one value.
Then directly after, when I call the API using the HttpClient, the API controller reports a different TraceId.
There are also no w3c trace context headers in the `Request` inside the controller method.

What am I missing here?

Comment: In your code you use `AddOpenTelemetryMetrics` which is for metrics. For traces you need `AddOpenTelemetryTracing`

Comment: My bad, copied the wrong section. I have the tracing section too. updating post

Answer (score 1):

I had a look into this and discovered that [`SocketsHttpHandler` has a code path to initialize a `DiagnosticsHandler`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/SocketsHttpHandler.cs#L486) that emits the HTTP request events, which other tools like [OpenTelemetry listen for to trace requests](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/src/OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.Http/Implementation/HttpHandlerDiagnosticListener.cs).

However, as the `HttpClient` used with `WebApplicationFactory` doesn't need to send network requests (as the test application is loaded within the same process), it has a custom [`ClientHandler`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Hosting/TestHost/src/ClientHandler.cs) that doesn't care about diagnostic events.

This sounds like an oversight in either `WebApplicationFactory` or OpenTelemetry, but either way it doesn't seem to work.

I think the workaround would be to pass a custom handler into `Factory.CreateClient`, and have that handler inject the [`traceparent`](https://www.w3.org/TR/trace-context/#traceparent-header) HTTP header manually based on [`Activity.Current`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.activity.current?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current)%3Bk(SolutionItemsProject)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-7.0), following the behaviour of the code in [TraceContextPropagator.cs](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/a274f06b2c4c3e76533695b0bd31e177c86b1a30/src/OpenTelemetry.Api/Context/Propagation/TraceContextPropagator.cs#L129) as a template.